# Can you make the question "status bar" in the iOS app more visible?

Tags: feature-request, design, ios-app

When reading a question in the iOS app, the bar showing the status, for example "closed," "locked," "on hold," is easy to miss until after reading through the whole question. Because it's located on the bottom of the page, I propose a few changes to increase visibility.

- The color is almost exactly the same as the question/answer text, causing it to blend in. A switch to something else, perhaps the blue used for "Add an answer," or even something brighter, like red, would alleviate that problem.
- The letters are small and difficult to differentiate from the question text. I'd prefer something larger.
- The banner itself is too short. The "Add an answer" banner is higher and draws immediate attention.

[image: On hold message] [image: Add an answer message]

Comment: Probably not blue since it would be confused with adding an answer. Maybe a yellow like on many of the websites?

Comment: @mhlester  I appreciate your interest. I definitely agree that yellow would be great.